# Magento - All categories have same image

Tags: image, magento, categories, catalog

So there's some code floating around that gets an individual subcategory's image:

```
foreach ($collection as $cat){
    $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');   
    $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
    $_img = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl();
}
```

Where `$cat` is the subcategory I'm trying to get the image of. The problem I'm running in to - the images for the subcategories are all the same! The first image from the subcategories is the image that shows up on the page. The links and names are all correct though: (this is also in the `for` loop)

```
<div>
    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($cat);?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $_img; ?>" title="<?php $cat->getName() ?>"/>
        <cite><?php echo $cat->getName();?></cite>
    </a>
</div>
```

I'm making this modification in `catalog/category/view.phtml`. There's a bit more to it than shown, but this is all the relevant information.

**Edit**

All categories have their own unique images, which are properly uploaded. They show in the admin correctly. Also, `$cat->getId()` is returning the correct id's for the individual subcategories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RandyHall, are your sure that $this->getCurrentCategory() will get the category from the same place as $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category); will set it to?

Watch the source code [here](http://magento-php-xref.tech-resolved.com/nav.html?app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php.source.html) and [here](http://magento-php-xref.tech-resolved.com/nav.html?app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php.source.html).
As you can see category is set to the layer model and get returns category from registry(via call to block).

So I would suggest you to do something like this:

```
$_img = $layer->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl();
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are doing wrong when getting image url.

**instead of using**

```
$_img = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl();
```

**try below code**

```
$_img = $cur_category->getImageUrl();
```

Comment: Anant is right. Because $cur_category is the variable in your cycle. And $this->getCurrentCategory() will return value from registry.

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov The idea was (from what I was reading) to set the current category to the one you were trying to get the image for, then get the current image.

Comment: @Anant This isn't working either... it just doesn't return anything. Also tried `$cat->getImageUrl();`, also nothing.

Comment: @RandyHall  What code have you used for loading the category collection? (ie: $collection)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($collection as $cat){
    $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
    $_img = $cur_category->getImageUrl();
}
```

Looks to me like this is what you are going for?